# Python Creating Array Properties

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python, still trying to learn it full. Below is a powershell snippet that i am quite used to creating array properties. If i have to convert this code in to python, can someone help with this.?

```
    $Target = @()
    
    #foreach ($Record in $Records)
       # {
    # SETUP ARRAY PROPERTIES
                 $TargetProperties=@{
                  "NAME"= $($Record.RecordToChange)
                   "TYPE" = $RecordType; 
                   "ZONE" =$Zone
                 }
          $TargetObject = New-Object PSObject –Property $TargetProperties
          $Target +=  $TargetObject
    }
```

so far have tried creating an instance object and then passing the values to this. example

```
    class myClass():
        myInstances = []
        def __init__(self, myStr01, myStr02):
            self.myStr01 = myStr01
            self.myStr02 = myStr02
            self.__class__.myInstances.append(self)


    # Create a test array inside test class and pass i,j


import attr
class testClass(object):
    
    def __init__(self,i, j):

        self.i = i
        self.j = j

    def CreateArray(self):
        import myclass
        import numpy as np
        # Create an object array
        for i in range(1,(self.i + 1)):
            for j in range(1,(self.j + 1)):
                test = myclass.myClass(i, j)
                print("Run number is ", test.myStr01, "Number is", test.myStr02)
        
        return test


    #From main function Call testClass
from testClass import testClass
    testClass(5, 6)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far (you'll only learn if you probe for yourself)?

Comment: i have tried creating an instance object class and then passing the values to this., but not sure if i am on the right track.